# Closing telnet connection gracefully from session mode itself without going to telnet prompt

Tags: telnet

a normal telnet connection is like this:

```
telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
^]
telnet> close
Connection closed.
```

I want to close it from telnet session itself without coming to telnet prompt by pressing.
My requirement is that if i press some control character from telnet session itself like CTRL+A so it will come out of session and close it automatically.
something like this:

```
$ telnet localhost 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
^A
Connection closed.
$
```

I tried all the options given at the man page and tried to do some $HOME/.telnetrc  file tests but couldn't  achieve it, as telnetrc will execute all the commands written in it with the given host whenever a telnet to that host is done.

Can anyone help me in this, like how it can be achieved.

Comment: it's so complicated..why you not use "exit"???its...more easy..

Comment: for using exit also i need to come to telnet prompt first. right.
while my requirement is to close the connection pr exit it from session mode without coming to telnet prompt(i.e. for coming to telnet prompt i need to first send escape character and then i can do close or exit).

Comment: @ Paul : I don't get you.
can you please tell me where can i find the solution.

Comment: Can you explain why one would want this? Telnet is just a *client program* to connect to some arbitrary service on some machine. If you use port 23 you connect to the telnet *service* and can terminate your login with `exit`, but this is a shell command, not a telnet command. You have to go to the telnet prompt to terminate a connection if the service you connected to doesn't offer a command to terminate the connection.

If you want to login to a remote machine via ssh use the `ssh` command, not `telnet` (unless you want to do manual encryption).

Answer (score 32):

No, the `telnet` client *(I'm guessing you are asking about the Linux one)* only supports **one** escape character, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (`^]`).

If you are just using `telnet` to make arbitrary TCP connections, consider using `netcat` or `socat` instead; these can be interrupted by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: For followers, you hold down ctrl, then hit the "right bracket" key, then hit enter.  It will respond with a prompt like `telnet>` and you can type in `quit` and hit enter to exit your session. Phew!

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks. That's way to exit on OSX.

Comment: What if I'm using a locale where they keyboard layout has the right bracket under alt-<some other key>? ctrl-alt-<the other key> isn't working.

Comment: Then you switch the keyboard layout, or use an on-screen keyboard...

Answer (score -4):

What about the good old <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, aka EOF?

Comment: it would work only if it is handled on the server side of session. Which is not true in general (and also not true in mentioned 22 port ssh connection).